# Iterating UIOutletCollection yields unpredictable results

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my ViewDid Appear method I iterate over UIOutletCollection.

```
for (UILabel *view in self.collection) {
    if (view.tag == 10 || view.tag == 11)
        view.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    else
        view.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
}
```

I have two of these views in collection set to tags 10 and 11, and others are 20-30 etc.
And all I get is changing one unrelated view with tag 90 change its text view to gray.

EDIT:

Question is, it does not change tag #10 or 11 text color to white, and it does not change other labels text color to gray. What is wrong?

Comment: What is your question? What is wrong?

Comment: @Popeye fixed question, sorry

Comment: Are you sure you have added all your labels to the collection?

Comment: Have you debugged and checked what the tag values are when textColor is set to white and when textColor is set to grey?

Comment: @Hjalmar This was the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an error.
It was the fact that only few labels were added when ctrl+dragging with multiple selected labels. I selected like 20, and it added only 3 of them.
And they all are labels.